# How can I access each element of a string array in java?

Tags: java, string

I was writing a function to reverse the position of words in a string without reversing the words themselves.
But I am not able to access the elements of string array. I am getting error with the following code.

```
 public static void reverseWords(String sd[]) {
   for(String s : sd){
    System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: and the error is....?  sd is an array, not a collection.

Comment: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

Comment: That is the problem with the caller code which calls `reverseWords()`. The caller is needed to pass a String array and not a String. The method you posted looks fine.

Comment: "sd is an array, not a collection" so how can i access each element of this array?

Comment: Yeah you are calling reverseWords with a String, not an array

Comment: Just use a regular for loop. You would not be able to "reverse" the words in the array even if arrays were collections.

Comment: *"sd is an array, not a collection" so how can i access each element of this array* - you already did it. You wrote a for-each loop that iterates over this array and the variable `s` holds each element.

Comment: @Ajithprasad looks like yes. I am not going into reversing elements etc. however, the method you posted looks just fine. Check the caller and post that code if possible.

Comment: For the record, the method is just printing each word in the array on its own line. It's not reversing anything.

Comment: If you have a sentence in a `String` just use `String.split(" ")` which will give you an array of the words _then_ you can call `reverseWords` on it, though you still need to change the logic inside of the method itself.

Comment: @fiveelements I checked with the caller code. It was actually passing a string instead of a string array.

Comment: @Ajith So create a `String` array using the `String` with `.split`.

Comment: A clear example with input and expected output would greatly help and increase the quality of your question. Additionally, it would clear up the confusion about what you actually want (see all the comments and the proposed answers which interpreted it wrong).

Answer (score 4):

To reverse the words in a String array do the following.

```java
public class Reverse{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] stringArray = {"Jim", "Jeff", "Darren", "Michael"};

        reverseWords(stringArray);

        for(String strings : stringArray) {
            System.out.println(strings);
        }
    }
    public static void reverseWords(String[] array) {

        for(int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++) {
            String temp = array[array.length-1-i];
            array[array.length-1-i] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```java
Michael
Darren
Jeff
Jim
```

To take in a String as an input try the following.

```java
public class Reverse{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String sentence = "Bob went to the store";
        String newSentence = reverseWords(sentence);

        System.out.println(newSentence);
    }
    public static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
        //This line splits the String sentence by the delimiter " " or by a space
        String[] array = sentence.split(" ");
        //for loop to reverse the array
        for(int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++) {
            String temp = array[array.length-1-i];
            array[array.length-1-i] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }

        //These next 4 lines simply take each element in the array
        //and concatenate them all into one String, reversedSentence.
        String reversedSentence = "";
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            //This if statement ensures that no space (" ") is concatenated
            //to the end of the reversedSentence.
            if(i == array.length-1) {
                reversedSentence += array[i];
                continue;
            }
            reversedSentence += array[i] + " ";
        }

        //returning the newly created reversedSentence!
        return reversedSentence;
    }
}
```

Output :

```java
store the to went Bob
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question at all.  He wants to reverse the _position_ of the `String`s in a sentence, but _not_ the letters themselves.

Comment: Now this answers what the OP was asking.

Comment: It might be helpful to show how to take in a `String` as the parameter instead of an array since apparently that is his only input and he can't change it then split it accordingly, but well done!  This should still be enough for him to understand.